# How to extract GPS metadata from cloud image in Google Photos in Android Studio?

Tags: android, geolocation, metadata, photo

I'm developing an Android app and one of the features is where you can place a marker on a map with the location of an image from your camera roll. If I select an image that is locally stored on the device it works perfectly, but selecitng a photo from Google Photos where it is not on my phone fails to retreive the GPS data. I have a loop to print out all the directories of the metadata and it's not showing up. I'm using https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/ for extracting metadata.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
private void chooseImage() {
    Intent chooseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    chooseIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(chooseIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePath));

                GpsDirectory gpsDirectory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(GpsDirectory.class);
                GeoLocation location = gpsDirectory.getGeoLocation();
                if (location != null) {
                    double lat = location.getLatitude();
                    double lng = location.getLongitude();

                    if (marker != null && !marker.getPosition().equals(new LatLng(lat, lng))) {
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        OverwritePositionDialog overwritePositionDialog = OverwritePositionDialog.newInstance(-1, new LatLng(lat, lng));
                        overwritePositionDialog.show(fm, "overwrite");
                    } else {
                        final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("New Spot").snippet(username);
                        mMap.addMarker(options);
                        moveCamera(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                        confirmPosition(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(filePath).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            Bitmap resizedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(resource, resource.getWidth() / 3, resource.getHeight() / 3);
                            Glide.with(context).asBitmap().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).load(resizedBitmap).into(imagePreview);
                            imagePreview.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(250);
                        }
                    });
                    Toast.makeText(CreateSpot.this, "Unable to get location from image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(filePath).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        Bitmap resizedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(resource, resource.getWidth() / 3, resource.getHeight() / 3);
                        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).load(resizedBitmap).into(imagePreview);
                        imagePreview.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(250);
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("error", String.valueOf(e));
            } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(filePath).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        Bitmap resizedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(resource, resource.getWidth() / 3, resource.getHeight() / 3);
                        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).load(resizedBitmap).into(imagePreview);
                        imagePreview.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(250);
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(CreateSpot.this, "Unable to get location from image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(filePath).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        Bitmap resizedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(resource, resource.getWidth() / 3, resource.getHeight() / 3);
                        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).load(resizedBitmap).into(imagePreview);
                        imagePreview.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(250);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                getContentResolver().delete(filePath, null, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you start your code with the used intent to pick a file please?

Comment: `filePath = data.getData();` That is not a file path but a file uri. And why is it defined global? Uri fileUri = data.getData();

Comment: `but selecitng a photo from Google Photos where it is not on my phone` But where is it then? And how did it came there? Take an image from your device (with geo tags) put it on the web and select with Photos again. What happens?

Comment: I defined filePath as global as I use it later on in my code, and I mean I'm selecting a photo from my Google Photos that is not stored locally on my phone, it's on the web already

Comment: I have updated the post with the way the intent used to choose an image

Comment: You can remove the setFlags call as you cannot grand anything. But... Have you done the test i suggested?

Comment: Yes I have done your test, it will only work if I keep the photo on the device after uploading to the web, if I remove the photo from my phone and then select the photo from the web it will not work.

Comment: If you with 'it will not work' that there is no location info in exif than that makes no sense to me. Please explain.

Comment: I have explained already, if I have the photo on my phone, my code works fine, it grabs the EXIF data of the location, however once it is uploaded to Google Photos and then removed from my device it does not grab the EXIF data anymore despite still being displayed within Google Photos. This is why I am asking this question here to understand how I can overcome this problem.

Comment: You should explain how existence of an original or removing an original from your phone can have influence in reading exif info from a copy on google drive. Makes no sense to me. What are the file sizes of original and copy. Are they equal?

Comment: How are you uploading to google drive? Using an intermediate bitmap?

Comment: It is not on Google Drive, it is on Google Photos. I have a Pixel phone, the original is a photo I have taken from my camera on my phone. When I upload the photo to Google photos, I have the option to delete from my device to free up storage while keeping it on the cloud within Google Photos, preserving the exif data when I want to download it again. It is however if I do not download it and select it within my app from the cloud that the exif data does not show up with the GPS information. The file sizes do not vary as they are being uploaded in original quality.

Comment: What are the file sizes. Please be exact as every byte counts. Uploading in original quality? Strange talking. One uploads a file. One should upload all bytes of the file. Next test,: Then download from google photos again. Store on your phone. How many bytes now? Determine exif tags again.

Comment: Yes uploading in original quality, have you not used Google Photos before? Maybe have a look at the service to better understand what I'm referring to. They are the exact same file size it does not matter what the size of the file is as I am referring to multiple images. The EXIF tags stay the same once the image is downloaded but not when I try to retrieve the image over the cloud.

Comment: `it does not matter what the size of the file is ` My god.. its the file size of original and uploaded one i was talking about. Google Photos is on my device but i do not let it use the cloud.

Comment: `Yes uploading in original quality, ` Still strange talking. Who is uploading: Google Photos or your app? Try ExifInterface to read those tags.